# count number of sentences in paragraph

Tags: python

Hi I am confused reading all the topics about counting sentences and words on here, I dont want to open any files, I just want to count the number of words and sentences in the string. I have the word count done and I am very happy with it, I just dont know where to go from here. Here's what I have so far.

```
    import re
    line = (" A Turing machine is a device that manipulates "
            "symbols on a strip of tape according to a table "
            "of rules. Despite its simplicity, a Turing machine "
            "can be adapted to simulate the logic of any computer "
            "algorithm, and is particularly useful in explaining "
            "the functions of a CPU inside a computer. The 'Turing'"
            " machine was described by Alan Turing in 1936, who "
            "called it an""a(utomatic)-machine"". The Turing "
            "machine is not intended as a practical computing "
            "technology, but rather as a hypothetical device "
            "representing a computing machine. Turing machines "
            "help computer scientists understandthe limits of "
            "mechanical computation.")
    print (line)
    print ()
    count = len(re.findall(r'\w+', line))
    print ("The number of words in this paragraph:", count)
```

The word count comes out with 98,which is perfect, I know there are mistakes in the paragraph but they are there on purpose so I know its working correctly. I now want to count the number of sentences which should be 5, but I'm unsure how. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the number of periods in the string, if you want to rely on those as your sentence delimiter.

```
line.count('.')
```

Or using a regular expression like you are doing for the words:

```
len(re.findall(r'\.', line)
```

Comment: Thanks man, worked perfectly

Comment: this, of course will count "hello..." as three sentences.