# splitting a text file based on paragraphs in python

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I am trying to split a text file based on paragraphs. I have already split them into a list. However my goal is to extract only those paragraphs which contains just one sentence. Is there any way to do that?

```
My text file is something like this:
paragraph1:
sentence
paragraph2:
sentence. sentence. sentence.
paragraph3:
sentence. sentence.
paragraph4:
sentence
```

I need only 1 and 4 as they have single sentence. I have already done below:

```
par = document.split(".\n")
```

Which has split the document into a list of paragraphs. But how do I extract only the ones with one sentence. Any ideas?

Comment: try to exlpore `nltk` library.

Comment: Please see if my answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

one approach could be to search for `.` in the paragraph. (note the `space` after the `.`). this might be a sign that the paragraph has more than one sentence.

so you could say something like:

`if '. ' in paragraph: 
  # don't print
else:
  # print`

just an idea...

Answer (score 0):

- The code below will help you to make changes as per your need.
- I am trying to return the para by para, after reading the content from
  given file.
- On each para, you can apply any condition you need before you `yield` from the generator.
- Below code is tested in 2.x

The content of file `My_text_file.txt` is:

> ```
> paragraph1:
> sentence
> paragraph2:
> sentence. sentence. sentence.
> paragraph3:
> sentence. sentence.
> paragraph4:
> sentence
> ```

My code is following:

```
import re


def gen_read_lines(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            yield line.strip()


def is_para_starting(line):
    return True if re.match("^paragraph\d+:$", line) else False


def gen_read_para(file_name):
    gen = gen_read_lines(file_name)

    para = []
    for line in gen:
        if is_para_starting(line):
            if para:
                #returning the previous para
                yield para
            para = []
        if ". " in line:
            #resetting para.
            para = []
            continue
        para.append(line)

    #returning last para.
    yield para


if __name__ == "__main__":
    para_gen = gen_read_para("My_text_file.txt")
    for para in para_gen:
        print "\n".join(para)
        print "~"*10
```

**Output is:**

> ```
> paragraph1:
> sentence
> ~~~~~~~~~~
> paragraph4:
> sentence
> ~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

**Edit:** condition added to check ". " in the line of para.

Comment: @v-shriram: see if this approach can help you.

Comment: thank you, but the code is printing the whole document

Comment: I have added condition to the above-updated code. Also, you can introduce the conditions as per your need too. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: thanks, i was wondering if there is a way to count the number of sentences in a list, which is already split based on paragraphs.

Comment: [line.count('.')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166774/count-number-of-sentences-in-paragraph) this link will help you. try `nltk` lib also.